# How to load a manually installed library?

Tags: python

I have a python library downloaded from [here](https://github.com/cerfacs-globc/icclim) and installed it in my home directory. This is for calculation of climate indices. In order to use this library in scripts I need something like:

```
from icclim import icclim
```

and

```
from iclim.util import callback
```

These commands do not work for me.
When I check the conda environment with

```
conda list -n base
```

I do not see icclim listed among the modules.
I have the same problem on ubuntu 18.04 and on centos 6.7.

Question is is there anything I can do to have this library listed in the environment, or simply to be able to call modules from it in a python script?

Comment: How did you install the library?

Comment: The icclim librry is a zipped file, so I just unzipped it and then "sudo python setup.py install" did not give any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice explanation of how Python, at least 2.7, finds packages.

https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

So you need to make sure your home directory shows up in `sys.path`. If it does not show up, the article explains how to add it. You could also just start python from your home directory.